# buscar email no banco e fazer aparecer num select com php

Tags: php

(este select é um exemplo) Bom eu tenho um aqui um select que servirá para enviar um email com phpMailer. Quero saber como eu posso fazer para que nesse select apareça somente os emails cadastrados no meu banco de dados "bancodados" dentro da tabela "professor". E-mail é um atributo de professor. Se precisar de mais informações é só dizer.

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select>
      <option value="" selected>Choose your option</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <label>email</label>
  </div>
```

Comment: Favor [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/215778/edit) sua pergunta, porque no jeito que está não da pra entender nada. Utilize [desse link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para se baseiar.

Comment: Está melhor assim?

Comment: E a tabela professor possui quais campos? idProfessor, nomProfessor e assim por diante? Vai passar essas informações do PHP para o HTML via AJAX ou possui o PHP juntamente com o HTML

Comment: campos nome, sexo, campus, email, senha, formacao. Uso PHP junto com HTML.

Comment: qual o nome da coluna que contem os e-mails?

Comment: Tabela professor coluna email.

Comment: veja a resposta se está mais fácil de entender  e faça o teste

Comment: fiz uma correção na resposta, acho que ficou bem fácil para vc entender

Comment: Não estou dizendo que deva ser a minha resposta a aceita,  mas leia este post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Com mysqli**

```
$con = new mysqli ("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "professor");
if($con->connect_errno){
    echo "falha na conexão";
    exit();
}
$consulta = "SELECT email,nome FROM professor";

$result = $con->query($consulta);

echo '<form action="Pagina_Destino" method="post"></form>

<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select>
      <option value="" selected>Choose your option</option>';

while($dados = $result->fetch_array()){
     $email = $dados["email"];
     $nome = $dados["nome"];
     echo "<option value=\"".$email."\">".$nome."</option>";
} 

    echo '</select>
    <label>email</label>
  </div>
  </form>';
```

Comment: Olha está dando erro nessa linha: $result = $con->query($consulta);
Se eu tiro ela aí não aparece o select

Comment: Essa linha não é PDO?

Comment: rapaz eu coloquei o que estava testando aqui no meu banco inclusive com meus credencias, eita

Comment: não é PDO é Mysqli

Comment: @JadsonAlves É Mysqli orientado a objetos, se não me engano. Qual o erro que está dando?

Comment: @JadsonAlves editei e esqueci de trocar nome do banco etc... por isso deve ter dado erro

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado. Você sempre responde minhas perguntas e sempre dá certo. obrigado mesmo,

Answer (score 0):

1) Utilize o PDO.

2) Efetue a conexão com o banco de dados utilizando o PDO.

```
$db_username        = 'usuario';
$db_password        = 'senha';
$db_name            = 'nomedobancodedados';
$db_host            = '127.0.0.1';

try {
    $mysqli_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_username, $db_password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Erro: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br>";
    die();
}
```

3) Determine uma variável que efetue a consulta SQL.

```
$results = "
SELECT colunadesejada AS 'emails'
FROM tableadesejada
WHERE filtrosdesejados
ORDER BY ordemdesejada
"
```

4) Utilize para executar.

```
$stmt = $mysqli_conn->prepare($results);
$stmt->execute();
```

5) Utilize para exibir os resultados.

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
echo '<div class="aaa">'.$row["emails"].'</div><br>'; //htmlquevocequiser
}
```

Sua pergunta não mostra nenhuma tentativa PHP, isso é uma pena.

Comment: Não seria em vez de colocar DIV, mas sim colocar OPTION, conforme o da pergunta ?

Comment: Por isso existe um comentário do lado da linha "htmlquevocequiser". Estou aqui para ajudar ele a construir o código e não para entregar pronto para ele.

Comment: Eu não sei quase nada de php, é um trabalho escolar. Esse códio em PDO não funciona, acho que tem a ver com o fato do resto não estar em PDO, não teria como fazer sem ser assim?

Comment: Você está utilizando MSQLI ou PDO no seu projeto?

Comment: MYSQLI. Eu tentei começar direto nesse PDO, mas não consegui entender. Aí fiquei no MYSQLI

Comment: O PDO é mais seguro e oferece suporte para vários tipos de bancos de dados, por isso dei a resposta utilizando ele. Tente mais uma vez com o PDO e diga qual erro você está obtendo, assim te ajudo a resolver por aqui.

Comment: Este é um código isolado, funciona de forma autônoma.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isto de forma simples utilizando o `mysqli_fetch_row()` do `mysqli`.

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','bancodados','senha', 'root'); //Infos do BD
$comando = "SELECT email FROM professor"; //Comando SQL
?>
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select>
        <option value="" selected>Choose your option</option>
        <?php
        if ($result=mysqli_query($connect,$comando)) //Checa se deu algum erro
        {
            $i = 0;
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) //Pega o resultado do comando para usa-lo
            {
                $i++;
                echo"<option value="$i">$row[0]</option>";//Adiciona o option
            }
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <label>email</label>
  </div>
```